# Next.js react-flags-select flickering on load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Can somebody help me solve this issue, I'm using `react-flags-select` to build an language selector in next.js. I can change the language but the component just filckers on load, I'll attach my code and a video. Can somebody help me solve this please?

```
<ReactFlagsSelect
            countries={['GB', 'RO']}
            selected={selected}
            onSelect={(code) => onFlagSelect(code)}
            showSelectedLabel={false}
            showOptionLabel={false}
            showSecondaryOptionLabel={false}
            selectedSize={20}
            optionsSize={20}
            className={styles.languageSelector}
          />
```

```
 const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(lng === 'ro' ? 'RO' : 'GB');

  const onFlagSelect = (code: string) => {
    if (code === 'RO' && lng !== 'ro') {
      router.push(`/ro/${pathname.substring(3)}`);
    }
    if (code === 'GB' && lng !== 'en') {
      router.push(`/en/${pathname.substring(3)}`);
    }
    setSelected(code);
  };
```

styles

```
.languageSelector{
    @apply mx-5
}
.languageSelector button{
    @apply rounded-3xl bg-teal-300 text-green-500 w-20 h-8
    shadow-lg py-0 px-2

}
```

Here's a link to a video that shows what is happening https://streamable.com/fmh2fm